# Ceph on Poweredge with what controller

Tags: ceph

I have a few old Dell Poweredge R510 servers lying around that I would like to use to deploy a Ceph cluster on and educate myself on Ceph as a backend for Openstack.  I am trying to determine what controller I can use in these servers that would be provide full drive passthrough to Ceph.

I am confident this is possible and a controller does exist for this server, because,http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/hardware-recommendations/, indicates a R510 was used as a reference production example on the Ceph web site (very bottom of the link included).  However, the hardware listing does not indicate what controller was used for the reference systems.  I am confident that it is not the Perc H700 as that controller does not support a passthrough mode.  However, I am unable to determine with certainty if an H300 has a passthrough mode or if a third party controller was used in the reference configurations.  Any assistance/knowledge on this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about small details (like 'drive pass-through') for educational/lab/experimental purposes. Just export each drive as a JBOD array (each array consists of a single drive).

Small details (like smart availability, writeback issue, etc) wouldn't be a problem for laboratory installation. Ceph requires a lot of knowledge and planing to be deployed, and a precise nature of used drives is not important, and CRUSH map is important. Focus on that.

In my lab settings I often use ram-disk with iscsi export which I mount back as iscsi disks on localhost. They are fast and works perfectly with all ceph utilities (including `ceph-disk`). It's not a production configuration but for sake of experiments and debug it works great. Moreover, I can do this on any kind of server or virtual machine, or my laptop, and I can have as much (i)scsi drives as I want (... or can fit in memory).

So any disks (NVME, raid, etc) is be good for educational/experimental purposes, as long as you have enough of them.